# Change output path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have mutipule web projects (please don't ask me why with multipule namespaces within them, I didn't create it. lol) and the dlls need to be compiled to the main web project. The problem is that I cannot give a disk directory path because we build on another machine and that directory path is different.

Is there a way that I can dynamically set the output path by the project name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to look at the post build events on the individual projects (Look in the Properties for a project, under the Build Events tab).  There you can create events that copy files and express the path via variables like {TargetPath} and {ProjectPath} that will be different for different setups.

Comment: Worked!

copy $(TargetFileName) $(SolutionDir)\WebRoot\bin

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The copy statement works like a charm in the Build Events. But if you need to go up a few folders you can do something like this in the Output path under Build tab.

..\bin\Debug\